# Map string in arrays to corresponding implemented class

Tags: java, interface, polymorphism, maps

I have an array with splitted `String` parts:

```
        String[] message = input.split("\\|");
        String[] parts;

        for (String line : message) {
            parts = line.split("-");
            //insert code here
        }
```

`parts` after split looks like this:

```
[MO, KB, 001]
[MO, PR, 001]
[MO, PR, 002]
```

where MO means MOUSE, KB =Keyboard, PR=Printer etc.

1. How can I extract the numbers (e.g. 001, 002) in the element and add it to a `Map` to be used as a `Key` and the `Values` are to be the corresponding Device keys e.g. MO, PR etc ensuring no duplicates of key and the values against the key? This would then enable to loop through the map and process each devices for the keysets...

   ```
    public interface Device {
       void create();

       void fix();
   }

    public Printer implements Device {
       public void create() {
           //logic to create
       }
   ```
2. When I lookup the list of devices to be created against a particular key I should get a `List` of `Devices` that are mapped to that key. For each key, I would like to create those `Devices` mapped to it. E.g. for key=001 create MO, PR & KB devices. How can I map these `String` value device keys to corresponding implemented class so when `create()` is invoked, it creates the device using implemented method for the sub-type.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/**
 * Created by bhanu on 30/6/16.
 */
class Ideone {

    /* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Map<String, List<String>> deviceByForename = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        Map<String, List<Device>> deviceMapped = new HashMap<String, List<Device>>();
        String[] parts = {"MO, KB, 001","MO, PR, 001","MO, PR, 002"};

        String[] devicesNames = null;
        for(String eachPart :parts ){
            List<String> devicename =  new ArrayList<String>();
            devicesNames = eachPart.split(",");
            if(deviceByForename.containsKey(devicesNames[2].trim()))
            {
                devicename = deviceByForename.get(devicesNames[2].trim());
                if(!devicename.contains(devicesNames[0])){
                    devicename.add(devicesNames[0]);
                }
                if(!devicename.contains(devicesNames[1].trim())){
                    devicename.add(devicesNames[1].trim());
                }
            }else {
                devicename.add(devicesNames[0]);
                devicename.add(devicesNames[1].trim());
                deviceByForename.put(devicesNames[2].trim(),devicename);
            }

        }
        Iterator it = deviceByForename.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            List<String> devicename =  (List<String>)pair.getValue();
            List<Device> mappedDevices =  new ArrayList<Device>();

            for(String device:devicename){

            switch ( device){
                case "PR":
                    Printer print = new Printer();
                    mappedDevices.add(print);
                    break;

                case "MO":
                    Mouse mouse = new Mouse();
                    mappedDevices.add(mouse);
                    break;
            };
            }
            deviceMapped.put((String)pair.getKey(),mappedDevices);
        }
        System.out.println(deviceMapped);
    }

}
interface Device {
    void create();

    void fix();
}

class Printer implements Device {
    public void create() {
        //logic to create
    }
    public void fix() {
        //logic to create
    }
}
class Mouse implements Device {
    public void create() {
        //logic to create
    }
    public void fix() {
        //logic to create
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not entirely clear to me what you're expecting in each step.
Starting with `MO-KB-001|MO-PR-001|MO-PR-002` you want a new map, containing:

```
001 - KB
001 - MO
001 - PR
002 - PR
002 - MO
```

(i.e. one `001-MO` got removed)

What you're looking for is Apache's [SetValuedMap<>](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/SetValuedMap.html)